# Error in integration of Hibernate and Ehcache in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, ehcache

I'm using Spring Boot 2.0 with JPA2 to annotate entities and hibernate as underlaying JPA implementation.

I wanted to use second level cache in that setup, so entities were annotated with @javax.persistence.Cacheable

I also added following in application.properties:

```
hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.format_sql=true
hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache=true
hibernate.cache.use_query_cache=true
hibernate.cache.provider_class=org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider
hibernate.cache.region.factory_class=org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory
hibernate.cache.region_prefix=
hibernate.cache.provider_configuration_file_resource_path=ehcache.xml
```

I also added this to pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

But still queries like entityManager.find(Clazz.class, pk) are firing DB query instead of using cached data.

Any idea what is missing?

Comment: `javax.persistence.Cacheable` ? I think you're using annotation from wrong package, try use this one from `org.springframework.cache.annotation` package.

Comment: Hi Kamal, currently we are using org.hibernate.annotations.Cache , do you want to replace this with org.springframework.cache.annotation?

Comment: You also need org.hibernate.annotations.Cache annotation that's where you set  usage startegy and region to use